# Java: Stack.pop() + incompatible types

Tags: java, stack, incompatibletypeerror

this is the first time I'm working with the Stack-structure. Here's the basic idea: I'm writing a text-based-adventure where the player can visit different rooms. Currently he can't go back. I thought I might use a Stack to document his movements. So if he moves on into a different room I used push() to put the currentCity (Which is an Object of the class City) onto the Stack. It looks like that:

```
private Stack history;
```

In the Constructor:

```
history = new Stack();
```

In the "go"-function:

```
history.push(currentCity)
```

If I try to retrieve the Object in my goBack-function like this:

```
currentCity = history.pop();
(currentCity is a private variable of the class I'm working in. It's of the type
City)
```

I thought that would work because the object ontop of my Stack is from the type City and so is the variable currentCity. Still I get incompatible types.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
stiller_leser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will either need to cast, or explicitly define your generic parameter for the stack. I recommend specifying the generic parameter.

```
private Stack<City> history;

history.push(city);
currentCity = history.pop();
```

Comment: Thanks - Stack history<City> did the job!

Comment: Hi there - just FYI, we see automatic flags from Community; there's no need for you to duplicate the flags as they are all filed under a special category for us. Duplicating the flags only serves to clog up the queue with extraneous flags. Thanks! You may flag this comment as obsolete once you've read it.

Comment: @BoltClock - was that directed at me? I'm not sure I follow your comment, could you elaborate more?

Comment: Yeah, we noticed some flags coming from you saying "More than 20 comments posted in the past 3 days". These are automatic flags that are already raised by the community user, so we see them already. But we're also seeing copies of those flags coming from you, so I was wondering.

Comment: Ah gotcha. I always wondered what the correct procedure for handling those sorts of flags were. They probably shouldn't be placed in the queue if they don't need further handling by the community, don't you think?

Comment: Oh, yeah... good question. I seem to have clean forgotten how the 10k queue works - but what you said makes sense, there really isn't any other way to remove a flag from the 10k queue. Maybe something for meta? We'll handle the flags as normal.

Comment: Sounds good. Was going to create a meta, but found [an existing one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144694/as-a-10k-user-what-should-i-do-with-the-too-many-comments-flag) already.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't giving nearly enough information for good help.  You don't show the declarations of everything, you don't give the exact text of the error message, and this is a case where a small self-contained example would have been quite easy and instructive, even to you.

pop() almost certainly returns Object, and in that case you'll have to cast it to City to overcome the error.  But I'm having to guess at several things here...

Comment: Well people where able to help me :) Still I agree, it wasn't a perfect post.

Answer (score 0):

The method is declared as `Object pop()`, so the compiler only sees `Object`, which is incompatible with `City`. If you used `Stack<City>`, then you'd have the method `City pop()` and it would work.

BTW `Stack` is an antiquated class, pre-Collections Framework. You are better off using `LinkedList`, which has `removeLast`, acting as `pop`.

Comment: :Thanks I'm using LinkedList now :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using a raw (untyoed) Stack. Use a typed Stack:

```
private Stack<City> history;

history = new Stack<City>();
```

then

```
currentCity = history.pop();
```

will compile.